# find the best fit between a long vector and a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I have a long vector $a \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times 1}$ representing spatial information, and a matrix $C = \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ representing spatio-temporal information, how to find a good fit of the row vector $b \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times n}$ (represents temporal information) so that $ab \approx C$?

One easy way seems to be to iterate each column of $C$ and find the ratio between its norm and norm(a), and use the ratio as entries for $b$, however, it treats each column of $C$ independently, so it's a pity not utilizing the correlations between the columns. I wonder if there's some standard way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a linear equation
$$ab^T = C \quad\iff\quad ba^T = C^T$$
You can solve for either vector in terms of the Moore-Penrose inverse of the other vector. In the case of vectors, there is an *exact formula* for the pseudoinverse:  $\quad v^+=\frac{v^T}{v^Tv}$

Therefore
$$\eqalign{
a^T &= b^+C^T \quad&\implies\quad &a = \frac{Cb}{b^Tb} \\
b^T &= a^+C   \quad&\implies\quad &b = \frac{C^Ta}{a^Ta} \\
}$$
NB: You wrote $b$ as a row vector, whereas I used column vectors in these formulas.

Comment: thanks for your detailed explanation. though there seems to be a typo in b's formula (last one)?

Comment: Yup, that was a typo. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The "least squares" approximation for $b$ is given by
$$
b = \frac{a^\top C}{a^\top a},
$$
where $M^\top$ denotes the transpose of $M$.